# How to advance other fields in datePicker automatically?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Let's say that I have a `UIDatePicker` and the mode is set to `.date`.
I want the following behaviour:

For example, March has 30 days. If I scroll below the 30th day, I want the month to be automatically incremented to April and so on.

Is there a property that does just that? I couldn't find one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to do what you want with a normal UIDatePicker. You could attach an action to the valueChanged event, but that doesn't get called until the date picker stops moving.

You could probably create a custom date picker using a standard `UIPickerView`. You could use the data source methods to figure out when the "wheels" are turned, call `selectedRow(inComponent:)` to figure out which values are selected for each wheel, and then call `selectRow(_:inComponent:animated)` to switch the month if the user scrolls the day past the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

> How to advance other fields in datePicker automatically?

The best way to do this is using the [Target-Action design pattern.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) Basically, when a user chooses a new date (action), the view (a target) does something.

Here's some code that changes the day value to 1 if it's set to 0:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doStuff(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(datePicker)
    ...
}

@IBAction func doStuff(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: sender.date)
    if components.day == 0 {
        // Using Calendar.current automatically takes care of Time Zones for us.
        if let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sender.date) {
            sender.setDate(date, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This example is in Swift 4.

No, there is no property that does this that I am aware of.

Comment: The problem with this is that the picker doesn't call a valueChanged action until the date picker stops turning. If you scroll past the end of the month and the day wheel keeps turning, you don't get notified. I think you'd have to create a custom picker as I outline in my answer in order to get the effect the OP is after.